# How to set up conditional breakpoints in spyder?

Tags: conditional-breakpoint

it was supposed to be incredibly simple to find answer in open internet but apparently not. How do you set conditional breakpoints in spyder (anaconda)?

for example here is a fraction of the code:

```
   if elem.name == "p":
      for b_elem in elem.select('b'):
         if not re_date.match(b_elem.text):
            speaker = b_elem.text.strip(':')
```

I want to set up a conditional breakpoint when speaker equals to  'Foreign National Offenders (Exclusion from the UK) Bill'

i tried to set  the red dot next to the speaker, right click and edit conditional breakpoint like this: speaker == 'Foreign National Offenders (Exclusion from the UK) Bill'

but the code does not stop at this breakpoint. I wonder why. Does anyone know how to set it up properly?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

The debugger stops at the row where you put the breakpoint **before** evaluating the row.
So, to have the debug stop based on the value of variable "speaker", you should insert the conditional breakpoint on a row below the one where "speaker" is defined.